# help identifying mega bloks parts. AM15057 and AM15049

Tags: part-identification, set-identification, clone-brands

Good morning, i took a old box i have in my room and i want to know from what sets of megabloks is this thing. The code from the gray parts is: AM15057, and from the big other is: AM15049.

1:
[image]

2:
[image]

3:
[image]